# Need Help regading Unity CN Controls Joystick

Tags: assert, unity-game-engine, joystick

I am learning unity 2D Games though video tutorials. The video tutorial I am following has used the older version of "CN Controls Joystick" (https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/15233).

Current version of "CN Controls Joystick" is completely  different from the older version used in the tutorial.

So, does anyone have older version of "CN Controls Joystick". If anyone have, please share with me for my practice.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

the older version its not necesary, you only have to know are the axis names of every joystick, i think now its easier, and I recomend you to open the example scene, and look for the scripts atached to the player... if you need more help, I can help you. only tell me what you want to done and ill show you how to do it.